# Load code for a MATLAB function block at Simulink runtime

Tags: matlab, simulink

I would like to have some file, `myfunc.m`, in my MATLAB path and somehow load its contents into a [MATLAB function block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) automatically just before the simulation starts. This way, I can use an external editor to write these embedded function, version control them separately as independent files, etc.

Is there a way to achieve this programmatically?

My initial attempt was to try and access the contents of the function block using something like `get_param`, but I can't seem to gain read/write access to the code itself.

Comment: Do you really need to modify the function block or is it acceptable to use a function block that does nothing else but call `myfunc`?

Comment: How is calling it right before the simulation start and at the start of the simulation any different?

Comment: @mars: I would prefer to modify it directly because I _think_ calling `myfunc` with something like `eml.extrinsic` or just using a block that calls a function in the MATLAB workspace slows down the overall performance.

Answer (score 2):

If the target `MATLAB Function` block doesn't already exist then you can add it as follows (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19494423/857390)):

```
load_system('eml_lib');
libname = sprintf('eml_lib/MATLAB Function');
add_block(libname,'myModel/myBlockName');
```

You can then modify the block's code using the Stateflow API:

```
sf = sfroot();
block = sf.find('Path','myModel/myBlockName','-isa','Stateflow.EMChart');
block.Script = 'Your code goes here';
```

See also [this post on MATLAB Answers](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102675).

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to add the folder containing the m-file to the default path. To do this:

(In the Command window)
Go to File -> Set Path -> Add Folder (choose the folder containing the m-file)

Now, you should use the InitFcn callback in the model properties to call your function. To do this, open the model:

(In the Model window)
Go to File -> Model Properties -> Callbacks -> InitFcn 
In the edit box provided for the InitFcn, write the command to call your function i.e. myfunc();
You will have to modify this command as per your function and requirements.

Once done, apply the changes to the Model Properties window and simulate the model.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that [model callbacks](http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2008/12/25/initializing-parameters/) may be a way to do what you want, though I have not used this technique myself.