# Programmatically change input to parameter in MATLAB Function block

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a [MATLAB Function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block wrapped in a masked subsystem. The subsystem's mask has a parameter `p1` which I want to use inside the MATLAB function. How to do this manually is [described in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/parameter-arguments-in-matlab-function-block-functions.html). However, I need to do this programmatically and so far I've failed to figure out how to do this.

Adding the parameter to the subsystem's mask programmatically [is easy using `Simulink.Mask.addParameter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/control-masks-programmatically.html), as is [creating the MATLAB Function block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19494423/857390) and [setting its code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22706370/857390). The hard part is to programmatically switch the scope of the function argument `p1` from "Input" to "Parameter" (Steps 2-4 in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/parameter-arguments-in-matlab-function-block-functions.html)). I couldn't find where this information is stored (I checked both the "traditional" Simulink block parameters and the Stateflow object associated with the block).

Comment: I don't think that's possible, or if it is, it's not documented as you have found out. The following is somewhat related http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/285859.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer [on MATLAB Answers](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100659). Use the following code to set the scope of input number `i` to `Parameter`:

```
% Get Stateflow root object
S = sfroot();

% Get block handle
B = S.find('Name','myBlockName','-isa','Stateflow.EMChart');

% Set scope
set(B.Inputs(i), 'Scope', 'Parameter')
```

Note that you can use `B.getChildren()` to access all inputs, outputs and parameters of the block. This is especially useful for parameters, since there is no separate `B.Parameters` list (as opposed to `B.Inputs` and `B.Outputs`).

Comment: Be careful using this. It will work if simulink model is running using matlab, but it will not work if you compile the model using simulink coder in order to create a executable model