# Editing the Code of a "MATLAB Function" Block in Simulink Programmatically

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'd like to create a simple Simulink model containing a ["MATLAB Function"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block programmatically -- i.e. using Matlab code.

Thanks to [this guide](http://blogs.mathworks.com/simulink/2010/01/21/building-models-with-matlab-code/), I've managed to create a new model containing the block:

```matlab
open_system(new_system('my_system'))
add_block('simulink/User-Defined Functions/MATLAB Function', 'my_system/my_func')
```

Usually, in order to edit the "MATLAB Function" block's code, one has to "open" the block by double-clicking on it then entering the new code.

However, I would like to set that code programmatically using e.g. [`set_param()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/set_param.html) or any relevant function.

For instance, to set the following as the block's code:

```matlab
function y = fcn(v)
%#codegen

y = 2 * u;
```

I would like to use something like:

```matlab
set_param('my_system/my_func', 'Script',...
    'function y = fcn(u)\n%#codegen\n\ny = 2 * u;'...
);
```

I've looked at the output of `get_param('my_system/my_func', 'ObjectParameters')` and tried to guess which parameter might be used to set the block's function code: So far, I couldn't find any. Therefore, my question is:

**Q: Is it possible, using only Matlab commands, to set the code of a "MATLAB Function" block in Simulink?**

Comment: This is an interesting question. Instead of editing the question, post an answer with whatever helped you.

Comment: @Ander Biguri: Done ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(As requested by @Ander Biguri, I've moved **a** solution that worked for me to a separete answer post. If anyone has an alternative/better approach, please feel free to post it as well)*

Well, it seems that this question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10335564/865719) before. *(perhaps formulated differently though?)* I've managed to solve my issue using the following code:

```matlab
sf = sfroot()
block = sf.find('Path','my_system/my_func','-isa','Stateflow.EMChart');
block.Script = sprintf('function y = fcn(u)\n%%#codegen\n\ny = 2 * u;')
```

Comment: The primary thing to note is that a `MATLAB Function` block is a `Stateflow` block  (or at least a part of one) in disguise.  Hence the needs to use `Stateflow` API functionality to manipulate the block.